# valid record in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

I have a table with few columns and one of the column is DockNumber. I have to display the docknumbers if they confirm to a particular format

First five characters are numbers followed by a - and followed by 5 characters. The last but one character should be a alpha.

```
12345-678V9
```

How can I check in SQL if the first 5 characters are numbers and there is a hyphen and next 3 are numbers and last but one is an alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this, you will have to figure it out on how to use this...

```
SELECT Case when 
Cast(ISNUMERIC(LEFT(@Str,5)) as int) + case when substring(@str,6,1)= '-' then 1 else 0 end +case when substring(@str,10,1) like '[a-z]' then 1 else 0 end =3
THEN 'Matched'
Else 'NotMatched'
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @gbn's answer, this checks to make sure the length is 11 (in case the @val is not a char(11) or varchar(11) and also checks to make sure the second to last char is alpha

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(20)
SET @val = '12345-678V9'
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(@val) = 11 AND @val LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9][0-9]' 
        THEN 'isMatch'
        ELSE 'isNotMatch'
    END AS [Valid]
```

Comment: [A-Z 0-9] needs to be [A-Z0-9] to disallow spaces, no?

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) can be your friend.

Comment: he did Say sql. but i'd say this is a better idea than his.

Comment: @Eric: no, OP said tags "sql" and "server" which usually mean ignoring the autocomplete for "SQL-Server"...

Answer (score 0):

```
LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
```

Now, this allows lower case a-z too. You'd need to coerce collation if you wanted upper case only

```
Value COLLATE Latin_General_BIN
       LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]' COLLATE Latin_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

PATINDEX is probably the ideal solution.

```
Select ...
From Table
Where PatIndex('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]', DockNumber) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Where  DockNumber Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9]
```

should work, but i would suggest using Regular expression in code. Much easier if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be `'^\d{5}-\d{3}[A-Z]\d$'`, because without `^` and `$` it would find longer strings that contain that sequence (122 **12345-678V9** 34).

Answer (score -1):

Use rule

```
CREATE RULE pattern_rule 
AS
@value LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
```

Then bind rule to column

Comment: it's deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx Use CHECK CONSTRAINTS